# Optimizing OpenGL ES application. Should I avoid calling glVertexPointer when possible?

Tags: iphone, optimization, opengl-es

I'm developing a game for iPhone in OpenGL ES 1.1; I have a lot of textured quads in a data structure where each node has a list of children nodes. So I traverse the structure from the root, and do the render of each quad, then its childs and so on.

The thing is, for each quad I'm calling glVertexPointer to set the vertices.

- Should I avoid calling it for each quad? Will improve performance calling just once for example?
- glVertexPointer copies the vertices to GPU memory or just saves the pointer?

Trying to minimize the number of calls will not be easy since each node may have a different quad. I have a lot of equal sprites with the same vertex data, but I'm not necessarily rendering one after another since I may be drawing a different sprite between them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

glVertexPointer keeps just the pointer, but incurs a state change in the OpenGL driver and an explicit synchronisation, so costs quite a lot. Normally when you say 'here's my data, please draw', the GPU starts drawing and continues to do so in parallel to whatever is going on on the CPU for as long as it can. When you change rendering state, it needs to finish whatever it was doing in the old state. So by changing once per quad, you're effectively forcing what could be concurrent processing to be consecutive. Hence, avoiding glVertexPointer (and, presumably, a glDrawArrays or glDrawElements?) per quad should give you a significant benefit.

An immediate optimisation is simply to keep a count of the number of quads in total in the data structure, allocate a single target buffer for vertices that is at least that size and have all quads copy their geometry into the target buffer rather than calling glVertexPointer each time. Then call glVertexPointer and your drawing calls (condensed to just one call also, hopefully) with the one big array at the end. It's a bit more costly on the CPU side but the parallelism and lack of repeated GPU/CPU synchronisations should save you a lot.

While tiptoeing around topics currently under NDA, I strongly suggest you look at the Xcode 4 beta. Amongst other features Apple have [stated publicly to be present](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html#instruments) is an OpenGL ES profiler. So you can easily compare approaches.

To copy data to the GPU, you need to use a vertex buffer object. That means creating a buffer with `glGenBuffers`, pushing data to it with `glBufferData` and then posting a glVertexPointer with an address of e.g. 0 if the first byte in the data you uploaded is the first byte of your vertices. In ES 1.x, you can upload data as `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` to flag that you intend to update it quite often and draw from it quite often. It's probably worth doing if you can get into a position where you're drawing more often than you're uploading.

If you ever switch to ES 2.x there's also `GL_STREAM_DRAW`, which may be worth investigating but isn't directly relevant to your question. I mention it as it'll likely come up if you Google for vertex buffer objects, being available on desktop OpenGL. Options for ES 1.x are only `GL_STATIC_DRAW` and GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW.

I've just recently worked on an iPad ES 1.x application with objects that change every frame but are drawn twice per the rendering pipeline in use. There are only five such objects on screen, each 40 vertices, but switching from the initial implementation to the VBO implementation cut 20% off my total processing time.

Comment: A doubt: to put all the quads in one array and then call glVertexPointer just once, I should add degenerate triangles, right?

Comment: Degenerate triangles allow you to link strips of polygons that aren't otherwise connected when you're drawing as GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP. If you're just using GL_TRIANGLES then they're unnecessary. If you're drawing a lot of disconnected quads then I don't think there's a massive reason to recommend either over the other; you still end up having to supply six indices or vertices per quad, and anything your card may theoretically save on setup for the shared edges in a strip (if anything; I don't know if common hardware does this in practise) is probably lost on setup for invisible quads.

Comment: Great, now I'm copying all the vertices to a common array before sending them to opengl, and though I make the copy of all the objects every frame, the game fps raised more than 2x! The time spent rendering went from 16 ms to 4 ms per frame. Thanks a lot! I'm using GL_TRIANGLES.